# LINQ read Select values

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a LINQ query where I want to select and read the `p.Api` value.

```
 var api = DataAccessNew.Instance.dcServers.Where(p => p.Ip == IpAddress).Select(p => p.Api);
```

How do I read the `p.Api` value?

I have tried `api.ToString()` but I get SQL instead of actual column value.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an `IEnumerable<>` back (and your `ToString` call is showing you the value of that expression).

If you are expecting a single value, do this:

```
var api = DataAccessNew.Instance.dcServers
    .Where(p => p.Ip == IpAddress)
    .Select(p => p.Api)
    .Single();
```

You might be interested to read about the other methods like Single():  `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`.  Which one you used depends on whether you are expecting a single or multiple values returned (Single vs. First) and what you want to happen if there are no values (the *Default methods will return the type default instead of throwing an exception).

Or if you want to look at all the returned values:

```
var api = DataAccessNew.Instance.dcServers
    .Where(p => p.Ip == IpAddress)
    .Select(p => p.Api);

foreach (var apiValue in api)
{
    // apiValue  will have the value you're looking for.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this snippet of code:

```
string apiValue = api.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

your syntex seems ok..

By the way try this

```
string api =DataAccessNew.Instance.dcServers.Where(p => p.Ip == IpAddress).Select(p => p.Api).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

if `p.Ip` is a unique key in your table you could try to add `.FirstOrDefault()` after your `Linq` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string getselectedvalue(ListBox l)
{ 
    string vtext="",vval="";
    var selectedQueryText = l.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
    var selectedQueryVal = l.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => item.Value);

    vtext= String.Join("','", selectedQueryText ).TrimEnd();
    vval= String.Join("','", selectedQueryVal ).TrimEnd();
    return v;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.